# Register Specific Module Constructor

Tags: nancy, tinyioc

I would like to inject different strings into each of my module's contructors. I register a factory method which constructs the module. I can then call `container.Resolve<T>()` and all is well. For some reason though when Nancy tries to resolve my module it throws the error

> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type:
>   Plugin.HomeModule ---> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException:
>   Unable to resolve type: System.String

```
public class HomeModule : NancyModule
{
    public HomeModule(string text)
    {
    }
}

protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
{
    base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);
    container.Register<HomeModule>((ctr, param) => { return new HomeModule("text"); });
    HomeModule module = container.Resolve<HomeModule>();
}
```

I have also tried doing the registration in `ConfigureRequestContainer()` with the same results. I have tried `container.Register<HomeModule>(new HomeModule("some text"));` as well as `AsSingleton()`.  I can register an implementation to the string type with `container.Register<string>("text")`, but this would inject the same string into all modules.

**How can I register a module constructor so that Nancy can resolve it?**

Answer (score 3):

Modules are obtained through the [INancyModuleCatalog](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/INancyModuleCatalog.cs), which is normally implemented by the bootstrapper, you'd have to create a custom variation of that - if you're using the default bootstrapper then this is the current implementation:

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/DefaultNancyBootstrapper.cs#L205

Comment: Since `INancyModule GetModule(TinyIoCContainer container, Type moduleType)` is sealed does that mean the best way for me to write a custom implementation of that method is to derive from `NancyBootstrapperWithRequestContainerBase<TinyIoCContainer>` directly?

Comment: Just create your own implementation of the catalog and register it in ConfigureApplicationContainer, I was only pointing to that method as an example of what the default implementation does, as it's slightly complicated by the fact that modules are registered in the request container, not in the main app container.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach for this would be to not pass in a primitive into your module, but us something richer, or perhaps a factory. The container can resolve those dependencies. Passing a plain string into the module is a sign of a problem somewhere else and a hint that your architecture probably needs rethinking

Comment: The container can also resolve a string type. Passing a factory which produces the value I want or a richer type when encapsulates the value when all I need is a string is poor design IMO. With Dependency Injection the class should always ask for exactly what it needs. The second and bigger problem with this is that the IOC would resolve the injected class to the same value (whatever is registered to it) for all modules which doesn't allow unique values passed to module constructor which is the core of the question.

Comment: Personally I think its good design, nothing worse than working on projects with ctors that require random string values making them harder to figure out wtf they are for or do or anything.

Comment: @Phill The code written above is just an arbitrary example, the constructor could take *any* kind of value or class. I wanted to show something simple to demonstrate what I am trying to do. I am a huge fan of Dependency Injection and I want to avoid reaching into global state for values that an object needs whenever possible. For this reason, I'm looking into how I can naturally pass data to my modules on a per-module basis. Since Nancy is integrated strongly with an IOC container I would've thought it would be easy to register module factories to customize how modules are constructed.

Comment: One of the key goals of dependency injection, and certainly our preferred approach of constructor injection, is to make it transparent what dependencies a particular class requires - passing in simple types like strings and ints goes completely against that principal.

Comment: Just ran across this issue myself. Decided to experiment with TinyIoC on the current project after previously using Ninject with Nancy. Ninject easily supports the injection of primitives rather than forcing the developer down the Factory path for something relatively simple; I'll be using Ninject again in future

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a custom catalog that registeres only Modules of a specific namespace, but I don't know where to register this.

```
public CustomModuleCatalog()
{
    // The license type is read from db in Global.ascx.
    // So I want to register a module based on a namespace. 
    // The namespace is the same like the license name.
    if(WebApiApplication.LicenseType == LicenseType.RouteOne)
    {
        var assemblyTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();
        var modules = assemblyTypes.Where(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.EndsWith("MyCustomNamespace"));
        var nancy = modules.Where(t => t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(INancyModule)));
        foreach (var type in nancy)
        {
            var nancyType = (INancyModule)type;
            _modules.Add(type, (INancyModule)Activator.CreateInstance(type));
        }
    }
}

public IEnumerable<INancyModule> GetAllModules(NancyContext context)
{
    return _modules?.Values;
}

public INancyModule GetModule(Type moduleType, NancyContext context)
{
    if (_modules != null && _modules.ContainsKey(moduleType))
    {
        return _modules[moduleType];
    }
    return null;
}
```